# Change the bootstrap tab url when click on tab using codeigniter base_url

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

On bootstraps tabs I would like to be able to change the url when I click on the tab.

Each tab has it's own href using codeigniter base_url, currently I use the `data-target=""` to change the tab but I need to be able to change the url as well

> **Question:** How can I change the url when I click on the bootstrap tab with out `#` because I use `data-target=""`

If I click on edit tab should change the url to

`http://project.com/user/1/edit`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php if ($page == 'profile') {?>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/' .$user_id. '/profile');?>" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#profile" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <?php } else {?>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/' .$user_id. '/profile');?>" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#profile" aria-expanded="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
    <?php if ($page == 'activity') {?>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/' .$user_id. '/activity');?>" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Activity</a>
    </li>
    <?php } else {?>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/' .$user_id. '/activity');?>" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Activity</a>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
    <?php if ($page == 'edit') {?>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/' .$user_id. '/edit');?>" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <?php } else {?>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/' .$user_id. '/edit');?>" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">2</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Something similar to the following code snippet should work.

```
$(function() {

  // capture click event on the tab
  $("a[role='tab']").on("click", function(event) {

    // stop the link from loading the new page
    event.preventDefault();

    // edit the current page url/title
    history.pushState("object or string", "Page title", $(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Does not change the url at all. I get window.history.pushstate is not a function